# Is it safe to create a Python class which is simultaneously sync and async iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, python-asyncio, async-iterator

Is it safe/bad practice to make a class both iterator and async iterator? Example:

```python
import asyncio


class Iter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
        self.elems = list(range(10))
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.i >= len(self.elems):
            raise StopIteration
        self.i += 1
        return self.elems[self.i - 1]
    
    async def __anext__(self):
        if self.i >= len(self.elems):
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        self.i += 1
        return self.elems[self.i - 1]


async def main():
    print("async usage:")
    async for elem in Iter():
        print(elem)
    print("sync usage:")
    for elem in Iter():
        print(elem)


try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except RuntimeError:
    await main()
```

I surfed the net and didn't find anybody asking similar question or discussing the problem.

Comment: There's a difference between allowing an instance to be used either synchronously or asynchronously, and trying to use the same instance synchronously and asynchronously *at the same time*. The important issue here is that the asynchronous iterator isn't re-entrant; access to `self.i` needs to be moderated across multiple iterators.

Comment: @chepner, my idea was that an instance will be used only either synchronously or asynchronously. Could you please explain why asynchronous iterator isn't re-entrant?

Comment: Neither one is re-entrant, because multiple calls would all be trying to share the state of `self.i`.

Comment: Everything that @chepner said, plus: I suspect that your example is too simple to illustrate the intended purpose.  The only reason to implement an iterator is to solve some sort of problem, and it seems to me that the solution would either require the use of an await expression or not.  That would tell you what kind of iterator you need.  Your example `__anext__` method doesn't have an await in it, so it's not a very useful example.  What problem do you have that suggests putting both types of iterators into the same class?

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is not the `sync` iterator: unless used in multi-threaded code it should be ok (but not otherwise).

Your async code, however, keeps the state in a single instance,  and if it is ever used in more than a task at once, the states will mix up.
(Also, if you have a single task using it, but nests iterations - async or otherwise - in the same instance).

It is easily resolved by returning an auxiliar object that will contain your `i` counter, for each of `__iter__`  and `__aiter__` - or simply return a generator with the counter in a closure - that is way easier than implementing `__next__` and `__anext__`:

```
class Iter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elems = list(range(10))
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.elems)
    
    def __aiter__(self):
        async def _iter():
            yield from iter(self.elems)
        return _iter
```

Now if you need some custom logic to *Actually* go into `__next__`, other than just sequentially yeld the values of a list, the associated iterator class logic can be of help:

```
...

class _InnerItter:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.i = 0
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.i >= len(self.parent.elems):
            raise StopIteration
        self.i += 1
        return self.parent.elems[self.i - 1]
    
    async def __anext__(self):
        if self.i >= len(self.parent.elems):
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        self.i += 1
        return self.parent.elems[self.i - 1]


class Iter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elems = list(range(10))
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return _InnerItter(self)
    
    def __aiter__(self):
        return _InnerItter(self)
...
```